# Javascript: How to return values from an array of hashes if a value is within a range

Tags: javascript

Javascript learner here.

Problem:
I have a list of hex ranges and I need to return a value if a query value is within a range. The data looks like this:

```js
[
  {...},
  {"start": 0x3C0000, "end": 0x3FFFFF, "country": "Germany"},
  {"start": 0x044000, "end": 0x044FFF, "country": "Ghana"},
  {...}
]
```

I have a hex value and I would like to get the country if the hex value is between start and end.

Question 1:
What would be the most efficient way to return country if query is between start and end?

Question2:
Would there be a smarter way to format the data which would allow a faster/more efficient query?

The goal of my questions is to learn alternatives to iterating through the array with a loop.

Comment: What "query" ? Please add some example input and expected output ... And depending on how many items your list has, optimization may not even be worth the effort.

Comment: Your data set would have to be quite large, before performance / "efficiency" of different approaches would actually start to matter. Considering the world has 195 countries, I rather doubt that is the case here to begin with. _"The goal of my questions is to learn alternatives to iterating through the array with a loop."_ - then go check out array methods such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: array.find(x => and check if query is between the x.start and x.end

Comment: A simple way of optimization could be, sorting the array by the `start` property. Then you can do a binary search in the list. Or you can create a [search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_tree)

Comment: @derpirscher: You're right, the explanation somehow vanished when I wrote the question. Probably inadvertently press shift when editing or something. Added the explanation now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular `for` loop would likely be the most efficient method.

That being said, there is an elegant solution with `filter` and `map`.

```js
let res = array.filter(o => x.start <= query && query <= x.end).map(o => o.country);
```

Of course, if you only want one result, then use `Array#find` instead.

```js
let res = array.find(o => x.start <= query && query <= x.end)?.country;
```

Comment: why is for loop faster than filter. is it because the map is not needed then?

Comment: @cmgchess In general, there is less overhead with a regular for loop. You can look at these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53072292/comparing-filter-and-for-loop-performance-in-javascript, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459395/why-using-for-is-faster-than-some-or-filter

Comment: @cmgchess Because with `filter` or `find` it will always have to call an additional function (ie the callback) for each element which produces some overhead.

Comment: Thank you @Unmitigated! For the solution and especially the links! They were quite interesting to read for a beginner!

Answer (score 0):

We can't do in *O(n)* if the range is not sorted. But for subsequent operations , we can do in *O(log(n))* given that range end points can be arranged in a number line without any internal fragmentation. (i.e [2,3] , [5,6] contains internal fragmentation but [2,3],[3,4] doesn't ).

So let us take the range values in question in the form
`{{x1,y1,v1},{x2,y2,v2}...{xn,yn,vn}}` and assume it is sorted. If not able to, then you can assume you can and consider it to have some null value.
So we get the range in number line as
`[x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3....xn,yn]` for our example where `y1<=x2,y2<=x3` ( other's comparisons are trivial as it is range endpoints ) .

Now create a array which holds the values of range end points. You can use either 1st end point or last endpoint of range. For our example , let us  take first end point. 0th  index corresponds to v1 , 1th to null ( there is no value in range `[y1,x2]` as mentioned earlier ). Here we use bisect python standard module for efficient indexing. Feed range of breakpoints(for our example , it is x1,y1,x2,y2 .. xn,yn) with your query value (let us take xi).
(You can apply the same logic in js )

```py
import bisect as bst

breakpoint = [x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3...xn,yn]
query = xi
rangeValueMap = [v1,null,v2,null...]

value = bst.bisect(breakpoint,query)

if value==null:
 print("No range covers the value {0}".format(query))
else:
 print("Value is %d"%(value))
```

Use the index returned from bisect to get value from already created array. If it null , then the range doesn't exist , else it does and use the value.